# Populate DropDown List dynamically

Tags: python, odoo, onchange, openerp-7

I am trying to populate my DDL(selection) from value of another DDL in OpenERP. Here is the code, that i have tried.

Here is my View XML:

```
<h1>
    <label for="categ1" string="Parent category"/>
         <field name="categ1" on_change="Product_Category_OnChange(categ1)" />
</h1>
<newline/>
<h1> 
    <label for="my_products" string="Products" /> 
         <field name="my_products" />
</h1>
```

My `_columns` for this view is like:

```
_columns = {
     'categ1':fields.many2one('product.category','Parent Category',required=True),
     'my_products':fields.many2one('product.product','Products')
}
```

my `onchange` function is like:

```
def Product_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ1):
    pro_id={}
    cr.execute('select ... where parent_id='+str(categ1))
    res = cr.fetchall()
    for i in range(len(res)):
            pro_id[i]=res[i]
    return {'domain':{'my_products': pro_id}}
```

The problem is, i am not getting filtered values for `my_products` bu instead getting all the values that are in `my_products`. Plz let me know, what i am doing wrong, or point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: you can use domain filters in xml or py why you try to do it on on_change ?

Comment: I tried it with domain filters both on Py file and in xml, but, actually i have to do it with query because of some self join and parent child relation in models. This is why I am doing it in `on_change` method. Any suggestion what is wrong.

Comment: if you please elaborate or post some link so that I can have some idea

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to show only the products that come under that category.

```
def Product_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ1, context=None):
    pro_id={}
    product_obj = self.pool.get('product.category')
    if not categ1:return {}
    categ_obj = product_obj.browse(cr, uid, categ1)

    return {'domain':{'my_products':[('categ_id','=',categ_obj.id)]}}
```

or in xml

```
<field name="my_products" domain="[('categ_id','=',categ1)]" />
```

Comment: Can we create a dropdown field because my values are returning but they all are displayed on 1 textbox along with the ids.

Comment: have you modified name_get function for product

Comment: I used cr.execute for running sql query in my onchange function to return the values. The values are ok but want to achieve them as adropdown or selection type menu

Comment: in xml you can use widget="selection". But I dont know why its showing ids in the dropdownlist

Comment: There is no drop down list in my code . When I use many2one ,it gives me TypeError: Object 29 has no method 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Like this way. It works my side

```
{'domain':{'my_products':[('id','=',categ1)]}}
```

Syntax is like this,

```
def Product_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ1, context=None):
        pro_id={}
        product_obj = self.pool.get('product.category')
        print product_obj.browse(cr, uid, categ1)
        cr.execute('select * from product_category where parent_id='+str(categ1))
        res = cr.fetchall()
        for i in range(len(res)):
            pro_id[i]=res[i]
        return {'domain':{'my_products':[('id','=',categ1)]}}
```

**Update:**

I understand, First of all, you have to make one Custom module.

put following code in your .py file.

```
class product(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        res = []
        cr.execute('select ... where parent_id='+str(ids[0]))
        resource = cr.fetchall()
        for r in resource:
            res.append((r.id, r.name)) # My assumption
        return res
```

Look this http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/trunk/view/head:/product/product.py#L778

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually i want to populate my_products from the query i have posted. I have a requirement that i should get data for my_product directly from query not by filtering using categ1 id. i hope t is clear now. Thanks