# How to override the dropdown selection list of a many2one field?

Tags: odoo, many-to-one

I'd need to customize the selection list of a many2one field, to include other items beside the standard ones (items of the parent which are not accessible from the domain filter)

Which method should I override?

Or should I create a custom onchange event method?

Comment: I'll override name_get like in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23563125/2411043

Comment: It would be strange if it could pull records from multiple models at once.